# How do I Center Images for a Javascript Slideshow when the width is unknown?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of images in a directory that I pull for a slideshow.
These images are random sizes. I need to center them no matter their width.
I can't set a manual margin because of the different widths. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.imgClass {
  width: auto;
  height: 380px;
}

.slideContainersContainer {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.slideshow-container {
  width: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transition: ease-in-out .7s;
  flexbox: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  padding: .2%;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideContainersContainer">
  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <!-- This section calls the first image. -->

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 1</div>
      <img class="imgClass" alt="" src="images/paintings/paintings1.png">
      <div class="text">
        <span class="title">Caption Text</span>
        <span class="origStat">Originoal Status:Sold</span>
        <a class="buyPrints">Purchase Prints</a></div>
    </div>

    <!-- This section calls the second image. -->

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
      <img class="imgClass" alt="" src="images/paintings/paintings2.png">
      <div class="text">
        <span class="title">Caption Text</span>
        <span class="origStat">Originoal Status:Sold</span>
        <a class="buyPrints">Purchase Prints</a></div>
    </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div><br>
  <div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  </div></div>
```

I added the rest of the code sorry for the inconvenience. Any Help Will Be Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("dot"); ` but there is no dot class

Comment: Your code example is getting this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined" Please fix that so we can look at your example.

Comment: iana css expert by any means but I don't think you need to know the width, just add the rule `margin: auto;` to horizontally center

Comment: will do i Give me a min

Comment: use this if you still have trouble: http://howtocenterincss.com can be pretty helpful in a pinch

Comment: ive updated the html with the buttons and dots

Comment: Just use some ready slide show code. There are like a million of them. You dont have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Dont want ready slide show code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox with the parent container of your images.

```
.mySlides {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

Comment: please, can you provide a code with images as examples?

Comment: i had to adjust some things but this did do it thank you i applied it to the slideContainersContainer class instead of mySlides and it did the trick Thank you.